# sympy autowrap (cython): limit of # of arguments, arguments in array form?

Tags: cython, sympy

I have the following issue:

I want to use autowrap to generate a compiled version of a sympy matrix, with cells containing sympy expressions. Depending on the specification of my problem, the number of arguments can get very large.

I ran into the following 2 issues:

- The number of arguments that autowrap accepts seems to be limited to 509.

i.e., this works:

```
import sympy
from sympy.utilities.autowrap import autowrap

x = sympy.symbols("x:509")
exp = sum(x)
cyt = autowrap(exp, backend="cython", args=x)
```

and this fails to compile:

```
x = sympy.symbols("x:510")
exp = sum(x)
cyt = autowrap(exp, backend="cython", args=x)
```

The message I get seems not very telling:

```
[...] (Full output upon request)
Generating code
c:\users\[classified]\appdata\local\temp\tmp2zer8vfe_sympy_compile\wrapper_module_17.c(6293) : fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
(compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\hash.c', line 884)
 To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++ 
 Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
LINK : fatal error LNK1257: code generation failed
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1257
```

Is there any way around this? I would like to use versions of my program that need ~1000 input variables.
(I have no understanding of C/cython.  Is this an autowrap limitation, a C limitation ...?)

Partly connected to the above:

- Can one compile functions that accept the arguments as array.

Is there any way to generate code that accepts a numpy array as input? I specifically mean one array for all the arguments, instead of providing the arguments as list. (Similar to lambdify using a DeferredVector). ufuncify supports array input, but as I understand only for broadcasting/vectorizing the function.

I would hope that an array as argument could circumvent the first problem above, which is most pressing for me. Apart from that, I would prefer array input anyways, both because it seems faster (no need to unpack the numpy array I have as input into a list), and also more straightforward and natural.

Does anyone have any suggestions what I can do?
Also, could anyone tell me whether f2py has similar limitations? This would also be an option for me if feasible, but I don't have it set up to work currently, and would prefer to know whether it helps at all before investing the time.
Thanks!

---

Edit:

I played around a bit with the different candidates for telling `autowrap` that the input argument will be something in array form, rather than a list of numbers. I'll document my steps here for posterity, and also to increase chances to get some input:

- `sympy.DeferredVector`

Is what I use with lambdify for the same purpose, so I thought to give it a try. However, **warning**:

```
A = sympy.DeferredVector("A")
expression = A[0]+A[1]
cyt = autowrap(expression, backend="cython", args=A)
```

just completely crashed my OS - last statement started executing, (no feedback), everything got really slow, then no more reactions. (Can only speculate, perhaps it has to do with the fact that A has no shape information, which does not seem to bother lambdify, but might be a problem here. Anyways, seems not the right way to go.)

- All sorts of array-type objects filled with the symbols in the expression to be wrapped.

e.g.

```
x0 ,x1 = sympy.symbols("x:2")
expression = x0 + x1
cyt = autowrap(expression, backend="cython", args=np.array([x0,x1]))
```

Still wants unpacked arguments. Replacing the last row by

```
cyt = autowrap(expression, backend="cython", args=[np.array([x0,x1])])
```

Gives the message

```
CodeGenArgumentListError: ("Argument list didn't specify: x0, x1 ", [InputArgument(x0), InputArgument(x1)])
```

Which is a recurrent theme to this approach: also happens when using a sympy matrix, a tuple, and so on inside the arguments list.

- `sympy.IndexedBase`

This is actually used in the autowrap examples; however, in a (to me) inintuitive way, using an equation as the expression to be wrapped. Also, the way it is used there seems not really feasible to me: The expression I want to cythonize is a matrix, but its cells are themselves longish expressions, which I cannot obtain via index operations.

The upside is that I got a minimal example to work:

```
X = sympy.IndexedBase("X",shape=(1,1))
expression = 2*X[0,0]
cyt = autowrap(expression, backend="cython", args=[X])
```

actually compiles, and the resulting function correctly evaluates - when passed a 2d-np.array.

So this seems the most promising avenue, even though further extensions to this approach I keep trying fail.

For example this

```
X = sympy.IndexedBase("X",shape=(1,))
expression = 2*X[0]
cyt = autowrap(expression, backend="cython", args=[X])
```

gets me

```
[...]\site-packages\sympy\printing\codeprinter.py", line 258, in _get_expression_indices " rhs indices in %s" % expr)
ValueError: lhs indices must match non-dummy rhs indices in 2*X[0]
```

even though I don't see how it should be different from the working one above.

Same error message when sticking to two dimensions, but increasing the size of `X`:

```
X = sympy.IndexedBase("X",shape=(2,2))
expression = 2*X[0,0]+X[0,1]+X[1,0]+X[1,1]
cyt = autowrap(expression, backend="cython", args=[X])

ValueError: lhs indices must match non-dummy rhs indices in 2*X[0, 0] + X[0, 1] + X[1, 0] + X[1, 1]
```

I tried snooping around the code for `autowrap`, but I feel a bit lost there...

So I'm still searching for a solution and happy for any input.

Comment: The [maximum number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034787/function-parameters-max-number) a C compiler has to be able to accept is 127 (but they're allowed to accept more). I would think an array argument would be the solution but I know very little about Sympy.

Comment: [Fortran doesn't appear to have a built in limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24673375/is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-arguments-passed-to-a-fortran-function), but I think f2py generates a C wrapper function, so probably isn't a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Passing the argument as an array seems to work OK

```
x = sympy.MatrixSymbol('x', 520, 1)

exp = 0
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    exp += x[i]

cyt = autowrap(exp, backend='cython')

arr = np.random.randn(520, 1)
cyt(arr)
Out[48]: -42.59735861021934

arr.sum()
Out[49]: -42.597358610219345
```

Comment: Didn't try/think of MatrixSymbol yet (so many indexed object in sympy...). Seems promising, I'll check it later and get back. Thanks for now!

Comment: To be honest, I'm not much of a sympy user, so there may be a better way to express this, but at least seems to work!

Comment: Quickly messing around with this answer shows `exp = sum(x)` also works.

Comment: Did get to work a little bit with the suggestion. It indeed does what my OP asks for nicely, so thank you again. However, unfortunately the elements of MatrixSymbol seemingly are not well integrated for other sympy routines, e.g. differentiation: `x[0].diff(x[0])` gives `Derivative(x[0,0], x[0, 0])` rather than `1`. Currently looking for a way to circumvent those problems, in the meantime still happy for any suggestions or hints to the OP.